# Чтение RTF файла в Swing

Tags: java, swing, rtf

Мне необходимо выводить файл с картинками на экран. Решил использовать формат RTF и выбрал библиотеку RTFParserKit. Все выводится, но вместо русских символов и знаков препинания идут квадраты.[image: Как выводится текст]

Я его вывожу следующим образом, только убрал кодировку при чтении, т.к. разницы нет, все равно квадраты.

```
 theoryPane.setEditorKit(new AdvancedRTFEditorKit());

    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("Приложения/Теория.rtf"));

        theoryPane.read(isr, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Это как то решаемо? Или лучше переделать под docx4j и считывать doc файл?